# List-Style-Type and Other Properties Not Working after Changing to Link

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

Hello and thank you in advance! I was going well with my website, until I had an issue. I changed my navigation menu, which is a list and in the header, from just plain text to links, but now it does not work. I changed the css rules relating to this navigation menu and added "a" to them. Now there are bullet points and the links go like this (with the bullets on the top right):

- q

  - q

    - q

Also my first list item is an image.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
#container {
    width=100%
    height:auto;
}
header #menuNav ul li a{
    bottom 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    line-height: 5.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #1d1e20;
    letter-spacing: 0.125em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    display: list-item;
    margin-left: 2em;
    clear: none;
    margin-right: 2em;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
header #menuNav .logo img a{
    bottom 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    line-height: 5.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #1d1e20;
    letter-spacing: 0.125em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    display: list-item;
    margin-left: 2em;
    clear: none;
    margin-right: 2em;
    list-style-type: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
header #menuNav ul li a:hover {
    opacity: 0.625;
}
header #menuNav .logo img a:hover {
    opacity: 0.625;
}
header #menuNav {
    width: 100%;
}
#contentGallery {
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<header>
   <nav id="menuNav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html"><span class="logo"><img src="images/Oculus_VR_Logo.png" alt="OculusLogo" width="142" height="68"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="Specifications.html">Specs</a></li>
    <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact-Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to style list items then style a tags in those list-items. These are diffrent tags and has diffrent attributes for styling.

```
header #menuNav ul li{list-style:none; ...styles for this tag}
header #menuNav ul li a{...styles for this tag}
```